# How to get permission to use Monster Manual images in articles and adventures “courtesy of Wizards of the Coast”?

Tags: intellectual-property, art, wizards-of-the-coast

We notice that a variety of online articles appear to have received permission from Wizards of the Coast for use of their images from the Monster Manual (such as [this Nerdarchy article](https://nerdarchy.com/out-of-the-box-dd-encounters-series-2-36-ouroboros/) which uses a Bone Naga image and cites it “courtesy of Wizards of the Coast.”).

We would like to do the same for an article or a published adventure, but don't know who to contact at Wizards.

Often there are one or two people in companies who are responsible for these types of permission or a particular department which one contacts.

**How does one receive permission from WotC for use of an image from the Monster Manual for an online article or published adventure?**

We are looking for an answer that worked in actual “gameplay” (i.e. actually tried and successful in real life) rather than the general approaches used to gain permission.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about MM artwork (or other artwork in published books you have in mind), or just "artwork generally from WotC"? I ask because I'm aware of a couple of libraries they've released for purposed use, but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you trying to do something beyond what's allowed by the [Fan Content Policy](https://company.wizards.com/fancontentpolicy)?

Answer (score 10):

[Wizards of the Coast's D&D support site](https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us) has a [Submit a Request page](https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) that explicitly includes Permission Request. When you pull up Permission Request, it also includes a link to the [Fan Content Policy](http://company.wizards.com/fancontentpolicy).